# How can I change ng-options value depends on other variable in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to change dropdown menu depends on checkbox. So if checkbox is checked, display only specific item(s).

```js
 <script>
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    
    $scope.colors=[
      {id:1, name:'black'},
      {id:2, name:'red'}, 
      {id:3, name:'white'},
    ]
    $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2]; // red
    $scope.isFlagOn = false;

    function showFlag(){
      if ($scope.isFlagOn){
        return [$scope.colors.find(s => s.name === $scope.myColor)];
      }
      else{
        return $scope.colors
      }
    }

  }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">

  <label>
     isFlagOn <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$scope.isFlagOn">
 
  
  </label>
  <br/><br/>
  <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color as color.name for color in $scope.showFlag() track by color.id">
    <option value="">Choose one</option>
    </select><br/><br/>

</div>
```

If checkbox is checked, I only want to show Red color option in here. Is it possible to use `ng-options`?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way. You can filter your ng-options with:

```
ng-options="color.id as color.name for color in colors | filter:{name: isFlagOn? myColor.name : ''} "
```

Also, `$scope` is bound to your HTML - *every* variable in there is automatically `$scope` so you don't use it in the HTML, only the JS (controller for example).

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.colors = [{id: 1, name: 'black'},
      {id: 2, name: 'red'},
      {id: 3,name: 'white'},
    ]
    $scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2]; // red
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label> isFlagOn <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isFlagOn">
  </label>
  <br/><br/>
  <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.id as color.name for color in colors | filter:{name: isFlagOn? myColor.name : ''} ">
    <option value="">Choose one</option>
  </select><br/><br/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like I don't need `showFlag` at all, right?

Comment: correct, I just removed it from the answer - this is the beauty of angularjs

Comment: And with boolean switches like that, you don't even need a $scope variable in your controller. I removed that too

Comment: Did this answer  your question?

Comment: This code snipet works! I just need to tweak it to apply my code.